# is there any detailed tutorial for uitableviewcontroller

Tags: ios4

i would like to  implement UITableViewController in an iphone application.I searched in the google but the tutorials are some what vague. could you provide some detailed tutorial for implementing UITableViewcontroller

Comment: What are you looking to do? The default table-view project that Xcode creates contains a fully operational table view controller.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a big fan of the [Cocoa with love](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/12/uitableview-construction-drawing-and.html) tutorial. It has a sample project and everything.